# how to email username and password to admin of new registration

Tags: email, user-registration

How can I send username and password of new registration to admin using email.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an action to do that, but you can't get the password because it's encrypted, unless you catch the password when the registration form is submitted but that's not a good practice.

Why do you need to get the passwords on admin email?
You can always reset password if the user forgot the password.

To send user information when a new user is registered:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'send_new_user_info_to_email', 10, 1 );

function send_new_user_info_to_email( $user_id ) {

    $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );

    $to = get_bloginfo('admin_email');
    $subject = 'New User';
    $body = 'User email:' . $user_info->user_email . '<br>User pass (encrypted):' . $user_info->user_pass ;
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send passwords via email because Wordpress encrypts them prior to storage. That's a behavior that can be changed, but you really shouldn't do it. If the admin needs to log into an user's account, you could code something using the [wp_set_current_user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_current_user) function, or you can use the [User Switcher](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-switching/) plugin.